# Sencha Touch 2.0.1.1 Local Store not saving values

Tags: extjs, touch, local-storage, local

I am trying to store in the local storage and its not getting stored. 
I need to store two values as state id and license type as 1 record and next time I will update it. So the store will always has 1 record like below.

```
{
 'stateId': 'NJ',
 'licenseType': 'BDL'
}
```

I tried for the last 2 days and with different option but its not storing.
Can someone please tell me what can be the problem in my code.

Note: I am trying to test is using Chrome browser.

Store Code

```
Ext.define("Sencha.store.TestParams", {    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: 
    [
        "Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage"
    ],
    config: {
        model: "Sencha.model.TestParam",
        autoSync: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'ezdt-test-params'
        }
    }
});
```

Model Code
Code:

```
Ext.define("Sencha.model.TestParam",
{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config:
    {
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields:
        [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'stateId', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'licenseType', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

Actual Code to save
Code:

```
var modTestParamInitialValues = Ext.create("Sencha.model.TestParam", {
    id: 'ezdt', //Always Same as there will be only one record.
    stateId: strSelectedState,
    licenseType: strSelectedLicenseType
});
storTestParams.add(modTestParamInitialValues);
storTestParams.sync();
```

Code I am using to retrieve the store value.
Always its printing as Not Set

```
var storTestParams = Ext.getStore("TestParams");
console.log("storTestParams#####-->" + storTestParams);
//storTestParams.load();
if(null != storTestParams)
{
    var intTestParamCount = storTestParams.getCount();
    if(intTestParamCount == 0)
    { 
        console.log("Not Set");
    }
    else
    { 
        console.log("Set Correctly");
    }
}
else
{ 
    console.log("Set Correctly");
}
```

I hope I give all the details. If you need any more details please let me know.

Thanks for your help.
Joseph

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you figured this out, since the question is old. I have had different troubles with syncing with localstorage since I first started developing with Sencha Touch 2. One thing that has helped me to get records into localstorage when syncing is to ensure that the `dirty` attribute of your model instance is set to true. You might want to try that. See: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-setDirty